# Question about the Limit of a Sum of a Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

I am a Calculus II student and we have been learning about series, summation, factorials, etc. I thought about this while I was in the shower and I cannot seem to get it out of my head.

What would this ever be equal to?

$\lim_{p\to \infty}\lim_{t\to p^-}\sum_{n=0}^t \frac{1}{(p-n)!}$

For the first real terms of $n$, it is clearly converged on 0. However, as $t$ approaches $p$ from the left side, the denominator begins to approach $0$. This would indicate that we are now adding terms that approach 1. For instance...

When $t=(p-1)$, the term is $=\frac{1}{p-(p-1)}=\frac{1}{p-p+1}=\frac{1}{1}=1$

Does it converge? Does it diverge? What would this series even look like as $n$ approaches $p^-$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{p\to \infty}\lim_{t\to p^-}\sum_{n=0}^t \frac{1}{(p-n)!}
 = \lim_{p\to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{1}{(p-n)!} = \lim_{p\to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{1}{n!} = e$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had suspected that this might be the case but I was not sure if there are other ideas that I had not explored. That is completely mind-boggling!

Comment: @Logo4000 You're welcome! The problem becomes a lot clearer when you remove the $t$; notice that it doesn't really contribute anything (you could add a whole chain of these without changing the result: $\lim_{p\to\infty}\lim_{t\to p}\lim_{u\to t}\lim_{v\to u}\ldots$).